# Kendo ui grid dropdown editor does not load data

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

Can not load data to kendo dropdown list. It gets data from backend but list is empty. BackEnd looks like:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetCities(DataSourceRequest command)
    {
        var cityModel = _uow.Cities.GetAll().ToList();


        var gridModel = new DataSourceResult
        {
            Data = cityModel.Select(PrepareCityModelForList),
            Total = cityModel.Count
        };

        return Json(gridModel);
    }
```

Front end

```
            schema: {
                data: "Data",
                total: "Total",
                errors: "Errors",
                model: {
                    id: "Id",
                    fields: {
                        Name: { editable: true, type: "string" },
                        City: { defaultValue: { CityId: 0, CityName: "Select City" } },
                        Address: { editable: true, type: "string" },
                        Tel: { editable: true, type: "string" },
                        Fax: { editable: true, type: "string" },

                    }
                }
            },
           ......
        columns: [...
        {
            field: "City.Name",
            title: "City",
            editor: cityDropDownEditor,
            template: "#=City.CityName#",
            width: 200
        }
 ....


function cityDropDownEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input required data-text-field="CityName" data-value-field="CityId" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({
            autoBind: false,
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read:
                    {
                        url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("GetCities", "Contact"))",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json"
                    }
                }
            }
        });
}
```

The city model has CityName (string), CityId (int) and CityPostalCode (string) fields. The only error in console is "Uncaught TypeError: e.slice is not a function"

upd* Code for PrepareCityModelForList

```
    protected virtual CompanyCityModel PrepareCityModelForList(City city)
    {

        return new CompanyCityModel()
        {
            CityId = city.Id,
            CityName = city.Name,
            PostalCode = city.PostalCode
        };
    }
```

upd*: returned JSON

```
{"ExtraData":null,"Data":[{"CityId":3,"CityName":"Minsk","PostalCode":"220000"},{"CityId":4,"CityName":"Brest","PostalCode":"224000"},{"CityId":5,"CityName":"Vitebsk","PostalCode":"210000"},{"CityId":6,"CityName":"Gomel","PostalCode":"246000"}],"Errors":null,"Total":4}
```

Comment: does the model have an "Id" field as well? As you have defined this on the kendo schema..might not be the problem, but maybe worth a look. Also, can you include the `PrepareCityModelForList` method.

Comment: updated. Id field is used for main model - that's not a city model - city is a property for main model

Comment: Ah yes, my bad. Try `field: "City.CityName"` instead of `City.Name` for the column definition...

Comment: Did not help. The loader gif still "runs" on select, and no elements found.

Comment: Hmm. Looking at the kendo custom grid editor demo, they refer to the whole object, not a property e.g in this case it would be `field:"City"` and let the template take care of the actual property to display (as you are doing)  Can you try that? [demo here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-custom)

Also, and I presume you have done this, but can you just confirm that the ajax call to `GetCities` is being made and have a look at the response using F12 tools on the browser - just to rule out data format issues, etc.

Comment: Sure, call to GetCities is made. Ajax makes a "POST" request as asked to - it returns json with 4 items. Making field: "City" changed nothing in behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in json, that was passed by ajax. You have to ensure your json is simple like:

```
      {[
          {"CityId":3,"CityName":"Minsk","PostalCode":"220000"}, 
            "CityId":4,"CityName":"Brest","PostalCode":"224000"}, 
            "CityId":5,"CityName":"Vitebsk","PostalCode":"210000"}, 
            "CityId":6,"CityName":"Gomel","PostalCode":"246000"}
      ]}
```