# kendo ui dropdown not binding

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo UI inline editing with dropdown list.
in my code, I get the values as JSON from controller function.

dropdown not binding this JSON data, it shows the error as e.slice is not recognized.

```
 $("#orderItems-grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: datasource,
        columns: [{
            field: "Orderref",
            title: "Order Ref",
            editable: false
        }, {
            field: "ProductRef",
            title: "Product Ref",
            editable: false
        }, {
            field: "ProductNotes",
            title: "Product Notes",
            editable: false
        }, {
            field: "OrderStatusId",
            title: "Order Status",
            template: "#=OrderStatus#",
            editor: function (container) {
                var input = $('<input id="OrderStatusId" name="OrderStatusId">');
            input.appendTo(container);
            input.kendoDropDownList({
                dataTextField: "Value",
                dataValueField: "Key",                    
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: {                                
                            url: "/Order/GetOrderStatusListForDD",
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType:"json"
                        }
                    }
                }

            }).appendTo(container);
        }
    },
    { command: { name: "edit", text: "Edit Status" } }],
    editable: "inline"
});
```

[image: Dropdown list]

MY JSON result is

{
"16":"Allocated to Picking Queue",
"2":"Awaiting Approval",
"10":"Awaiting Order to be placed",
"9":"Awaiting Stock",
"6":"Cancelled",
"14":"Cancelled and Product Reset",
"7":"Denied",
"8":"Discontinued",
"11":"Discontinued and Alternative Found",
"15":"Invoiced",
"1":"Order Received",
"3":"Order sent to Supplier",
"5":"Shipped",
"4":"Storage Area"
}

Comment: Got the right jquery version?

Comment: yes. how to display this json with keyvalue pair like {"Key":"16","Value":"Allocated to Picking queue"}

Answer (score 0):

you have twice .appendTo(container). Try this:

```
editor: function (container, options) {
    $('<input data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({
            dataTextField: "Value",
            dataValueField: "Key",  
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "/Order/GetOrderStatusListForDD",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json"
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

**Update:** in your GetOrderStatusListForDD() action the result must implement IEnumerable, then return Json(result) will return right JSON

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. but still i got error as e.slice is not a function while binding

Comment: above i mentioned my JSON result data in question. please suggest how to bind this data to kendo ui dropdown

Comment: your json should be an array, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29943753/kendo-ui-grid-dropdown-editor-does-not-load-data

Comment: Now I altered my json using stringbuilder. "{[{Key:16,Value:Allocated to Picking Queue},{Key:2,Value:Awaiting Approval},{Key:10,Value:Awaiting Order to be placed},{Key:9,Value:Awaiting Stock},{Key:6,Value:Cancelled},{Key:14,Value:Cancelled and Product Reset},{Key:7,Value:Denied},{Key:8,Value:Discontinued},{Key:11,Value:Discontinued and Alternative Found},{Key:15,Value:Invoiced},{Key:1,Value:Order Received},{Key:3,Value:Order sent to Supplier},{Key:5,Value:Shipped},{Key:4,Value:Storage Area}]}". but now while binding the value undefined loaded in dropdown.

Comment: {Key:2,Value:"Awaiting Approval"} - add quotes to value, because it is string

Comment: Hi Gene, thanks for your reply. I just returned the result as list. now it solved my issue. Thank you so much.